# Open Emacs GUI from terminal (keep process running in terminal)

Tags: osx, install

Sorry, but I will probably be not using the correct terminology in this post.

I used to be able to open Emacs from my terminal and the terminal process would stay open (I would not be able to navigate anywhere else using the terminal unless I opened a new tab of quit Emacs). It would look something like the following:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ emacs



# and down here would just be open space
```

But now when I open Emacs, the terminal reverts back to where I can navigate to another directory or whatever:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ emacs
MacBook-Pro:~ User$
```

However, I prefer the terminal process to stay open which allows me to easily close Emacs when it freezes (by just exiting the terminal) instead of powering off my computer. I am not sure what I did to cause this change in behavior.

Comment: You are saying that Emacs now automatically "backgrounds" the process (like `emacs &`)?  In the past, did the terminal have emacs, or did it wait for your GUI version of emacs?  When you type `which emacs` and `emacs --version` what do you get?

Comment: what causes emacs to freeze, by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your emacs is running as a background process for some reason.
I would have to guess why (see below).

You could try to get emacs back to foreground by running `fg` immediately after running emacs (do it at the same command prompt).

```
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ emacs
MacBook-Pro:~ User$ fg
```

**Why** is emacs running in the background: there are several possibilities

- you assigned an shell `alias`, which runs `emacs &`, when you call `emacs`
- you set up emacs to run in server-mode (i.e. with the `--deamon` option, this could also be an `alias`)
- something else

Btw: [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/02/force-quit-mac-apps/) and [here](http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/12/kill-process-by-name-command-line/), you can read how to kill a process, which is frozen. So you do not need to reboot your computer.